# How to run command after source env shell inside bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment

I am trying to run a command after setting up an environment. This command runs a python script which depends on the environment.

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/some/linux/env/shell
python test.py
```

However, the "python test.py" only runs after I exit the env shell.
I want to be able to run the "python test.py" inside this new shell env.

Comment: Can you clarify what is inside `env shell` ? what information is lost  ? The 'source' command will execute the .../env/shell in the current bash, and any exported variables will be passed to the python code.

Comment: Nothing is lost. Only that the next line after source will never be executed unless I exit the new shell (in this case type the exit command). I would like to find a way to execute this "python test.py" inside that new shell.

Comment: I checked again and the `env shell` is creating a new bash shell with rcfile. I could edit the `env shell` to include the python line but I would like to avoid this case. I want to keep it as it is.

Comment: consider sharing the ‘shell’ file. Hard to provide feedback without knowing what is in it. It probably fork an interactive shell, but impossible to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly adding python running and interpreting directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And you have to give a code execution authority. You can give a permission below

```
chmod a+x test.py
```

Now you can run it from the command line.

```
./test.py
```

Comment: nope. not the answer. test.py runs fine. I want to run it while inside the env shell not after exiting the env shell.

Comment: Maybe you try this way.  ""/usr/bin/environments/project/env/bin/python test.py""